# How can I use jquery to hide a drop down menu when the user clicks outside of the menu area?

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I want the user to be able to click on the words "Click Here" and toggle between showing/hiding the drop down. This works fine. I also want the user to be able to click outside of the drop down area and hide the drop down menu if it is currently displayed. How do I do this?

jquery:

```
function dropDown() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myID').load('my_file.php',function(){
            document.getElementById("myID").style.visibility="visible";
            $('#myID').slideToggle('fast');
        })
        return false;
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<div onclick="dropDown()">Click Here</div>
<div id="myID"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#myID {
visibility:hidden;
z-index:9999;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: You don't need a document.ready function there

Comment: As I noted in my answer, why use `onclick` when the jQuery semantically handles it much better (it is easier to see what is going on, and Javascript action is contained in one place, not buried in the HTML code)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `visibility:hidden` attribute from the code

Attach the click handlers for both the `div` and the `document`

```
$('.dropdown').on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#myID').slideToggle('fast');
});

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).hasClass('dropdown') || $(e.target).attr('id') === 'myID'){

    }
    else{
      $('#myID').hide();     
    }
});
​
```

**CSS**

```
#myID {
    z-index:9999;
    display:none;
    width:200px;
    height:300px;
    background-color: orange;
}​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/xC7fq/)**

If you want to use `visibility:hidden` in your code then you need to omit the `display:none` and vice versa...

Answer (score -1):

For the click inside, since you are already using jQuery, you should have the HTML:

`<div id="myDropdown">Click Here</div>`

With the jQuery:

```
$('#myDropdown').click( function(e){
        $('#myID').load('my_file.php',function(){
            $('#myID').show('fast');
            e.stopPropagation();
        })
        return false;
  });
```

Then to have it roll up when clicking, but not on the `myDropdown`, your jQuery should be:

```
$(":not(#myDropdown)").click(function(){
      $('#myID').hide('fast');
});
```

See a working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/2YuLy/

Comment: @Yury, why?  The OP said "I also want the user to be able to click outside of the drop down area and hide the drop down menu if it is currently displayed."

Comment: Do you understand what this line of code is actually doing? It finds every single element in the most inefficient way I can imagine. Then it adds event listener to ALL elements. Plus there is such thing called event bubbling which means your handler will be triggered multiple times on every parentNode from target to document.

Answer (score -1):

```
function dropDown() {
        $('#myID').load('my_file.php',function(){
            document.getElementById("myID").style.visibility="visible";
            $('#myID').slideToggle('fast');
        });

        $(':not(#myId)').bind('click', toggleDropdown);

        return false;

}

var toggleDropdown = function() {
      $('#myID').slideToggle('fast');
      $(':not(#myId)').unbind('click', toggleDropdown);
};
```